# OpenMP - Poor performance when solving system of linear equations

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I am trying to use OpenMP to parallelize a simple c++ code that solves a system of linear equations by Gauss elimination.

The relevant part of my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

#define nl "\n"

void LinearSolve(double **& M, double *& V, const int N, bool parallel, int threads){
   //...  
   for (int i=0;i<N;i++){  
      #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads) if(parallel)
      for (int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
         double aux, * Mi=M[i], * Mj=M[j];
         aux=Mj[i]/Mi[i];
         Mj[i]=0; 
         for (int k=i+1;k<N;k++) {
            Mj[k]-=Mi[k]*aux;
         };
         V[j]-=V[i]*aux;
      };
   };
   //...    
};  

class Time {
   clock_t startC, endC;
   time_t startT, endT;
   public:
      void start() {startC=clock(); time (&startT);};
      void end() {endC=clock();  time (&endT);};          
      double timedifCPU() {return(double(endC-startC)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);};
      int timedif() {return(int(difftime (endT,startT)));};
};

int main (){
  Time t;
  double ** M, * V;
  int N=5000;
  cout<<"number of equations "<<N<<nl<<nl;

  M= new double * [N];
  V=new double [N]; 
  for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
     M[i]=new double [N];
  };

  for (int m=1;m<=16;m=2*m){
     cout<<m<<" threads"<<nl;

     for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
        V[i]=i+1.5*i*i;
        for (int j=0;j<N;j++){
           M[i][j]=(j+2.3)/(i-0.2)+(i+2)/(j+3); //some function to get regular matrix
        };
     };

     t.start();
     LinearSolve(M,V,N,m!=1,m);
     t.end();

     cout<<"time "<<t.timedif()<<", CPU time "<<t.timedifCPU()<<nl<<nl;
  };
}
```

Since the code is extremely simple I would expect that the time would be 
inversely proportional to the number of threads. However the typical result I get is (the code is compiled with gcc on Linux)

```
number of equations 5000
1 threads
time 217, CPU time 215.89

2 threads
time 125, CPU time 245.18

4 threads
time 80, CPU time 302.72

8 threads
time 67, CPU time 458.55

16 threads
time 55, CPU time 634.41
```

There is a decrease in time, but much less that I would like to and the CPU time mysteriously grows.

I suspect the problem is in memory sharing, but I have been unable to identify it. Access to row M[j] should not be a problem, since each thread writes to the a different row of the matrix. There could be a problem in reading from row M[i], so I also tried to make a separate copy of this row for each thread by replacing the parallel loop by

```
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(threads) if(parallel)
  {
     double Mi[N];
     for (int j=i;j<N;j++) Mi[j]=M[i][j];
     #pragma omp for 
     for (int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
        double aux, * Mj=M[j];
        aux=Mj[i]/Mi[i];
        Mj[i]=0; 
        for (int k=i+1;k<N;k++) {
           Mj[k]-=Mi[k]*aux;
        };
        V[j]-=V[i]*aux;
     };
  };
```

Unfortunately it does not help at all.

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: You're using `clock()` on Linux which returns the cumulative time for each processor not the wall time. This is one of the two most common mistakes the openmp tag. Somebody made this same mistake a few days ago. Do a search for clock and openmp and you will find many questions/answers addressing this already. Use `omp_get_wtime()` and then make a table with these numbers.

Comment: You should state exactly what your hardware is. Intel or AMD? How many cores? Does it have hyper threading (or modules if AMD). Is it a multiprocessor system (NUMA system?).

Comment: I run my calculations on distant computer cluster. The computers are made of 6-10 core Intel Xeon processors, but I do not know more hardware details. I have tested the code on several different computers with more or less the same results.

Comment: I use clock() to measure the CPU time. I could replace time() by omp_get_wtime(), but I have checked that they give me the same results.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is excessive OpenMP synchronization.

Having the #omp parallel inside the first loop means that each iteration of the outer loop comes with the whole synchronization overhead.

[image: OpenMP profile from inside Allinea MAP]

Take a look at the top-most chart on the image here (more detail can be found on the [Allinea MAP OpenMP profiler](http://www.allinea.com/blog/201502/profiling-openmp-allinea-map-50) introduction).  The top line is application activity - and dark gray means "OpenMP synchronization" and green means "doing compute".

You can see a lot of dark gray in the right hand side of that top graph/chart - that is when the 16 threads are running.  You're spending a lot of time synchronizing.

I also see a lot of time being spent in memory access (more than in compute) - so it's probably this that is making what should be balanced workload actually be highly unbalanced and giving the synchronization delay.

As the other respondent suggested - it's worth reading other literature for ideas here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the underlying problem may be that traditional Gaussian elimination may not be suitable for parallelization.

Gaussian elimination is a process where by each subsequent step relies on the result of the previous step i.e. each iteration of your linear solve loop is dependent on the results of the previous iteration, i.e. it must be done serially. Try searching the literature for "parallel row reduction algorithms".

Also glancing at your code it looks like you will have race condition.